# What is the better or easier way to create "nested" menus in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

##### So in XML you were able to structure menu items and nest them like this.

[image: xml menu structure]

---

But in jetpack compose, I am unable to figure out how this would work.
I already read and built a simple drop down menu from [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#dropdownmenu). But trying to do the same as XML in jetpack compose doesn't make much sense. The menus are created separately and independent. I am looking for something simpler and better than that.

[image: jetpack-compose menu]

Comment: Does it render the required UX?

Comment: It renders everything fine except it doesn't show the menu as a submenu of the menu item. It just displays it as a second separated menu, which doesn't seem to be the correct way to implement that.

Comment: Then I think you will need to implement a custom one. Wait, even in the xml system, didn't you want the other menu to just appear alongside this parent one?

Comment: I mean if so, then all you need to do in this case is just add an arrow symbol at the item, then wrap the other menu inside an `AnimatedVisibility`

Comment: I already thought of a solution like that:
put an arrow, attach the submenu and animate it. But if you compare it to the XML part, this is way more work and not like the standard solution. I am trying to find something standard (if there is something that I am looking for), if not, then I think I will have to go with your suggestion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about something like this?

Create a composable for your main menu, and one for your nested menu.

#### Main Menu Composable

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MainMenu(
    menuSelection: MutableState<MenuSelection>,
    expandedMain: MutableState<Boolean>,
    expandedNested: MutableState<Boolean>
) {
    DropdownMenu(
        expanded = expandedMain.value,
        onDismissRequest = { expandedMain.value = false },
    ) {
        DropdownMenuItem(
            onClick = {
                expandedMain.value = false // hide main menu
                expandedNested.value = true // show nested menu
                menuSelection.value = MenuSelection.NESTED
            }
        ) {
            Text("Nested Options \u25B6")
        }

        Divider()

        DropdownMenuItem(
            onClick = {
                // close main menu
                expandedMain.value = false
                menuSelection.value = MenuSelection.SETTINGS
            }
        ) {
            Text("Settings")
        }

        Divider()

        DropdownMenuItem(
            onClick = {
                // close main menu
                expandedMain.value = false
                menuSelection.value = MenuSelection.ABOUT
            }
        ) {
            Text("About")
        }
    }
}
```

#### Nested Menu Composable

```kotlin
@Composable
fun NestedMenu(
    expandedNested: MutableState<Boolean>,
    nestedMenuSelection: MutableState<NestedMenuSelection>
) {
    DropdownMenu(
        expanded = expandedNested.value,
        onDismissRequest = { expandedNested.value = false }
    ) {
        DropdownMenuItem(
            onClick = {
                // close nested menu
                expandedNested.value = false
                nestedMenuSelection.value = NestedMenuSelection.FIRST
            }
        ) {
            Text("First")
        }
        DropdownMenuItem(
            onClick = {
                // close nested menu
                expandedNested.value = false
                nestedMenuSelection.value = NestedMenuSelection.SECOND
            }
        ) {
            Text("Second")
        }
    }
}
```

Then place them in your main drop down menu composable.

#### Top Bar Composable

```kotlin
@Composable
fun TopAppBarDropdownMenu(
    menuSelection: MutableState<MenuSelection>,
    nestedMenuSelection: MutableState<NestedMenuSelection>
) {

    val expandedMain = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val expandedNested = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    // Three Dot icon
    Box(
        Modifier
            .wrapContentSize(Alignment.TopEnd)
    ) {
        IconButton(
            onClick = {
                // Expand the main menu on three dots icon click
                // and hide the nested menu. 
                expandedMain.value = true
                expandedNested.value = false
            }
        ) {
            Icon(
                Icons.Filled.MoreVert,
                contentDescription = "More Menu"
            )
        }
    }

    MainMenu(
        menuSelection = menuSelection,
        expandedMain = expandedMain,
        expandedNested = expandedNested
    )
    NestedMenu(
        expandedNested = expandedNested,
        nestedMenuSelection = nestedMenuSelection
    )

}
```

The `menuSelection` and `nestedMenuSelection` parameters of `TopAppBarDropdownMenu` would allow implementing actions in the `TopAppBarDropdownMenu` host depending on which state is activated from the menu. Something like this:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MainScreen(
    /* some params */
) {
    
    val menuSelection = remember { mutableStateOf(MenuSelection.NONE) }
    val nestedMenuSelection = remember { mutableStateOf(NestedMenuSelection.DEFAULT) }
    
    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                title = { Text(text = stringResource(R.string.app_name)) },
                actions = {
                    TopAppBarDropdownMenu(
                        menuSelection = menuSelection,
                        nestedMenuSelection= nestedMenuSelection
                    )
                }
            )
        }
    )
}
```

Not sure it's the "right" way to do it but it works for me.

You could potentially make it easier to instantiate nested menus by creating a `NestedMenu` composable with more parameters, which would make it easier to reuse. Just keep in mind that [Material Design guidelines recommend using Cascading Menus only on desktop](https://material.io/components/menus#dropdown-menu).

Comment: It's probably currently the only way to implement that, so I will mark this question as solved. Hope to see a simpler implementation from android in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering this question as well.
At present, I compose this nested Menu like this:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun ExpandableDropdownItem(
    text: String,
    dropDownItems: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    var expanded by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }
    DropdownMenuItem(onClick = {
        expanded = true
    }) {
        Text(text = text)
    }
    DropdownMenu(
        expanded = expanded,
        onDismissRequest = { expanded = false }
    ) {
        dropDownItems()
    }
}
```

This can be used with other DropdownItems.
And that's not the best solution : the place of the nested Menu is strange.

Answer (score 0):

I made a nested menu variation for sorting that seems to work well using AnimatedVisibility.

When expanding, it switches the top level menus visibility to the submenus, and can even add a back button if needed, but more levels might get confusing with the switches.

```
@Composable
fun NestedSortMenu(
    onSortClick: (SortOrder) -> Unit
) {
    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var orderType: OrderType by remember { mutableStateOf(OrderType.Ascending) }

    AnimatedVisibility(visible = !expanded) {
        Column {
            DropdownMenuItem(onClick = {
                orderType = OrderType.Ascending
                expanded = !expanded
            }) {
                Text(text = stringResource(R.string.ascending))
                Icon(
                    Icons.Filled.NavigateNext,
                    contentDescription = stringResource(R.string.ascending),
                    modifier = Modifier.size(20.dp)
                )
            }
            DropdownMenuItem(onClick = {
                orderType = OrderType.Descending
                expanded = !expanded
            }) {
                Text(text = stringResource(R.string.descending))
                Icon(
                    Icons.Filled.NavigateNext,
                    contentDescription = stringResource(R.string.descending),
                    modifier = Modifier.size(20.dp)
                )
            }
        }

    }
    AnimatedVisibility(visible = expanded) {
        Column {
            DropdownMenuItem(onClick = {
                expanded = !expanded
                onSortClick(SortOrder.Title(orderType))
            }) {
                Text(text = stringResource(R.string.title_menu))
            }
            DropdownMenuItem(onClick = {
                expanded = !expanded
                onSortClick(SortOrder.Format(orderType))
            }) {
                Text(text = stringResource(R.string.format_menu))
            }
            DropdownMenuItem(onClick = {
                expanded = !expanded
                onSortClick(SortOrder.DateAndTime(orderType))
            }) {
                Text(text = stringResource(R.string.date_and_time))
            }
        }
    }
}
```